# How can I iterate over a pair of strings rune by rune in Go?

Tags: go

What's the idiomatic Go way of iterating over two strings and comparing them rune by rune?

Given my limited understanding of Go, a simple way to do this would look like:

```golang
arunes := []rune(astr)
brunes := []rune(bstr)
for i, a := range arunes {
  b := brunes[i]
  // do something with a and b
}
```

Which works ok when `astr` and `bstr` are short or a full scan is required anyway, but when they are long and there is a high chance of breaking the loop early, this may be inefficient because from what I understand, `[]rune(..)` requires a full scan of the string. In particular, if the strings are very long, and I only need to look at, for example, the first 1% of the two strings, I want to avoid scanning the entire string.

(my first thought was for some sort of `zip`, but afaik, this doesn't exist in Go, and due to the lack of generics, the function signature would have looked really gross anyway - but if Go did have a good clean alternative to `zip`, I would be most delighted and excited to learn about it)

TL;DR Is there an idiomatic Go way to iterate over runes in pairs of strings while still being efficient when only a small fraction of the two strings need to be looked at?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [utf8.DecodeRuneInString](https://pkg.go.dev/unicode/utf8#DecodeRuneInString) to get runes from each string.

```
s1 := "hello world"
s2 := "Hello, 世界"
for {
    r1, n1 := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(s1)
    r2, n2 := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(s2)

    // DeocdeRuneInString returns a zero size rune
    // at the end of the string. I break the loop
    // here when the end of a string is reached. Update
    // the logic as appropriate for your application.
    if n1 == 0 || n2 == 0 {
        break
    }

    // Process the runes.
    fmt.Printf("%c %c\n", r1, r2)

    // Advance to next rune.
    s1 = s1[n1:]
    s2 = s2[n2:]
}
```

[Run the example on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/dDeD3efBiTn).